# Would R be sufficient for handling this task?

Tags: python, r

I am working on a project that requires visiting about 1000 websites and extracting information from each website. The information is the starting and ending date of an official in his/her political tenure.

I have limited programming experiences. R is a statistical package, which I think is easier to learn. Python would be more powerful. But the learning time would be substantial.

My questions is, would R be sufficient for handling this task. If yes, what packages would be involved. Are there any helpful tutorials on web scraping in R that you can recommend. I am reading http://www.r-bloggers.com/. If not, are there any tutorials about Python webscraping you would recommend.

Comment: Python is, IMHO, the easiest-to-learn and most powerful language i've ever seen. This doesn't mean it's ABSOLUTELY the easiest or ABSOLUTELY the most powerful BUT if you add both components, you'll get the best language in that "category".

Comment: based on the answers, the python guys seem much nicer, too

Comment: R is a language for statistical analysis, Python is for general purpose. You can do general programming in R, but it is more difficult than statistics in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, R is sufficient for your task. You can use the package "XML". Check out this
[quick guide](http://www.omegahat.org/RSXML/Tour.pdf).

If R or python is the best tool for your task depends on what you want to do with the data after downloading it.

Answer (score 0):

Python would be my first choice in this situation. R is not an easy language to learn, whereas Python is designed so that it is. And you'll find tons of tutorials to help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are enough resources for python to get what you are trying to do up and running with in a day to a few days. Theres a lot of sample  code on the web and enough libraries for python to make scraping websites a breeze. Look at [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and [lxml](http://lxml.de/)